# Awk in Python subprocess not working

Tags: python, awk, subprocess

I'm trying to run:

```
p3 = subprocess.Popen('awk \'{ print $6 "\t" $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $5 }\''.split(' '), stdin=p3.stdout, stdout=f)
```

but receive the error:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
     >>> ' <<< 
    missing }
awk: bailing out at source line 1
```

Has anyone run into this issue before?

Comment: Always try to mention O.S with your questions for better understanding.

Comment: python can read files, why are you calling out to awk?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you're looking for:

```
cmd = ['awk', '-v', 'OFS="\t"', '{print $6, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=[what are you reading from?], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
result = p.stdout.read().split(' ')
```